# Can bad table-scan queries slow down nice index-covered queries at the same instance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, index, memory

Let's say we have an instance used by two clients: me and my friend Ivan. Each of us has his own database. Each of us is only reading.

I'm a bad guy, so I'm relentlessly shooting table scans at the db. My tables are also huge, so they don't fit into memory.
Ivan is a nice guy, so all of his queries are covered by an index, so he has no reasons to hit the disk at all.

Will he notice any problems?

AFAIK, I'll have a bunch of threads sitting there in `SUSPENDED` state waiting for disk, and not generating too much of a load otherwise, so Ivan should do just fine.

Comment: Indexes (like tables) are read from disk and kept in memory. So if your queries load (your tables) data into memory and kick other (Ivan's index) data out of memory, his queries will be affected, no?

Comment: Totally makes sense. But I guess I just assumed that SQL somehow would get that it's me who is the villain here. Does it prioritize indexes over the data itself when deciding on what to keep in memory? I mean, if overall size of table is 10x the RAM available, it wouldn't help me that much if SQL dropped the indexes, which are tiny when compared to the table.

Answer (score 5):

I can definitely say "Yes, your bad query can impact Ivan's query" due to resource competition at instance level.

I have multiple databases in one production sql server box, I have seen many times that a bad query (actually a SP) in one database that caused both CPU and I/O usage skyrocketed and impact all other user sessions connected to other databases.

Besides CPU and I/O usage, one particular case is the negative impact a bad query brings to TempDB performance, and when TempDB is heavily utilized, it is a direct hit to all other queries that need to use TempDB for their executions.

Comment: Yep **"resource competition"** is the crucial element.

Comment: ...and can be at server level (instance isolation might not be enough, though you have more mechanisms to control resource contention).

Answer (score -3):

Isn't here where that the significant role of DBA come to picture by monitoring, analyzing and making corrective course of action to iron-out for the best use of resources?